# Delphi VirtualStringTree - Indenting Problem

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

Hey S.O! I realized my child nodes are not being indented - they are on the same level as the root nodes. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As you see, the childnodes are on the first level's Indent. FixedIndent is OFF, so thats not whats causing it..

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to use Skype's icons like that?

Comment: And do you think your contacts would approve of you broadcasting their Skype IDs to the entire world like that?

Comment: @David, yes, those selected few are all internet marketers - thats all they do basically. I gave them free exposure. ;) Also, they have all agreed to help out with the development of my program (suggestions, testing, etc), hence the category "xSky". Skype's Icon's are used freely with their API.

Comment: @jeff that's very enlightened of Skype!

Comment: @David - what exactly do you mean? Skype would not make something available for public use, if you were not allowed to use it. ;)

Comment: @Jeff Some corporations wouldn't let others using their branding but by letting others do so, Skype will get free marketing. I consider that to be enlightened.

Comment: @David - Ah, yes, of course. They even provided a wrapper for their API - examples in Delphi, Skype's mother language ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the check boxes are indented slightly. Keep in mind that the control only indents *one* column. All other columns are treated like ordinary table columns. Set the `Header.MainColumn` property to 1 if you want the "Full Name" column to be the one showing indented items. Then set the `Indent` property.

You can also handle the `OnBeforeCellPaint` event. Adjust the dimensions of the `ContentRect` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I just read up on the documentation - I had the Indent to 1, cause I thought it affected all the nodes :P